# Is there any way in BTRFS to set compression permanently?

Tags: mount, compression, btrfs

I have a USB HDD.

I want to mount it with compression enabled. I can do in the fstab of my system or even using udev rules. The problem is that I won't mount my USB HDD on my computer only. Up to now, I used to trigger a terminal each time I mounted it.

Then, I discovered `chattr +c`. This is working very well **but** I want to use LZO instead of ZLIB. Is there any way to be more specific and define the compression algorithm once for all?

Answer (score 8):

btrfs will compress every file changed since it was mounted if you use:

```
mount -o compress-force=lzo /dev/btrfsdev /mnt/btrfsmnt
```

If you want to see to it that ALL files get compressed this way, I've got a little script I wrote to do it...

```
du -ht +$((1024*1024)) "$HOME" |\
    sed -rn 's/^[^/]*(.*)/btrfs fi defrag -fvclzo "\1"/p' |\
        sudo sh -n
```

The above only works on my *`$HOME`* directory - but you can use it on anything or everything as you like. It's also got the *`-n`* operand fed to *`sh`* as is so you can see for yourself what *`sh`* is currently ***`not`*** doing before removing it to tell it to do it.

Anyway, first it queries *`du`* for files in *`human-readable`* format *(probably redundant here since we strip that in the next step anyway)* that are larger than *`1MB`* or *`$((1024*1024)).`*

It *`|pipes`* its info to *`sed`* which strips off everything before the leading *`/, "quotes"`* the filename, builds the *`btrfs filesystem defragment -verbose -flush-to-disk -compress-lzo \filename`* command and hands it over a *`|pipe`* to *`sudo sh`* to execute.

Again, it won't do anything so long as *`sh --no-execute`* is in effect, though.

I think some *very* recent *`btrfs`* userspace tool builds do defragment entire directories recursively, but if so it's a pretty new thing, so I've always had to do stuff like this.

Comment: That's a very nice answer. However this is what I already did (this is what I implied by "Up to now, I used to trigger a terminal each time I mounted it."). I'd like to know if there is any way to associate default mounting flags with the FS. If you don't have root, none of these work.

Comment: Default mounting flags? Well, you can definitely use fstab. And with btrfs, you can mount by subvolume as well, so you could associate, as you say, a subvolume with specific mount options and with the user= mount option, you could give it to the user. You might wonder - but how do I make a subvolume out of the files I already have? If you create an empty subvolume then cp --reflink everything you want in it that should do the job.

Comment: Also the defrag job above could be a cron job...

Comment: `compress=lzo` is sufficient, you don't need to re-compress compressed binary files like PNG.

Answer (score 8):

From what I read, you can set the `compression` property on the root of the subvolume to achieve this [0, 1]:

```
sudo btrfs property set /mnt/your-subvolume compression lzo
```

After grabbing your Btrfs subvolume UUID with `sudo btrfs filesystem show /mnt/your-subvolume`, you can then validate that the LZO compression feature is currently enabled with:

```
cat /sys/fs/btrfs/<UUID>/features/compress_lzo
```

It should return 1 if it's enabled.

[0]  https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression

[1]  https://www.berthon.eu/2016/setting-shared-folder-compression-on-synology-nas-btrfs/